# How to make a one dimensional scatterplot of points in time?

Tags: r, time, plot

I want to create a one dimensional scatterplot of points in time (range of about 5 hours), to visualise e.g. the time when I get up in the morning.

I tried

```
time=rep(Sys.time(),100)+round(3600*rnorm(100),1)
stripchart(as.numeric(time), main="stripchart", method="jitter", jitter = 2)
```

but that gives me
[image]

where I believe time is given in seconds since epoch. I'm interested in times of the day(8:02, 7:50,...) so time in seconds does not work for me. I need `as.numeric` however as I get 'invalid first argument' for leaving it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plot the chart without the x-axis labels with `xaxt="n"` and add it afterwards with hours and minutes using `axis`. I'm using `pretty` to get the beginning of the hour.

```
time=rep(Sys.time(),100)+round(3600*rnorm(100),1)
stripchart(as.numeric(time), main="stripchart", method="jitter", jitter = 2, xaxt="n")
axis(side=1,pretty(time), format(pretty(time),"%H:%M"))
```

[image]

Comment: I like it. Didn't realize you could suppress an axis like that.

Comment: Thank you so much! I get `Error in axis(side = 1, pretty(as.numeric(time)), format(pretty(time),  : 'at' and 'labels' lengths differ, 5 != 4` half the time though...

Comment: Remove `as.numeric` in the `axis` line.`axis(side=1,pretty(time), format(pretty(time),"%H:%M"))` I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
time=rep(Sys.time(),100)+round(3600*rnorm(100),1)
minutes <- (time - min(time))/60
stripchart(as.numeric(minutes), main="stripchart", method="jitter", jitter = 2)
```

Which yields this (x-axis in minutes):

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I was being unclear. I'm really interested in time on the clock like 8:02 , I'll edit the question to better reflect that.